# How to "reverse direction" of POSIX message queue in Linux?

Tags: c++, posix, message-queue

I am trying to figure out how to "reverse" a single POSIX message queue to enable two-way communication between a client and server process while only using one POSIX message queue (i.e. only one memory segment at a time). This is, in essence, a half-duplex setup where two-way communication is supported, but messages can only flow in one direction at a time.

The standard approach is to use one queue for client -> server and one queue for server -> client as shown below (this is basically my current code).

Client:

```
...
int read = mq_open("servertoclient", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0600, 0);
int write = mq_open("clienttoserver", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0600, 0);
char send_buffer[8192];
mq_send(write, send_buffer, 8192, 0); //send message to server
char receive_buffer[8192];
mq_receive(read, receive_buffer, 8192, 0); //receive response from server
mq_close(write);
mq_close(read);
mq_unlink("servertoclient");
mq_unlink("clienttoserver");
...
```

Server:

```
...
int write = mq_open("servertoclient", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0600, 0);
int read = mq_open("clienttoserver", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0600, 0);
char send_buffer[8192];
mq_send(write, send_buffer, 8192, 0); //send message to client
char receive_buffer[8192];
mq_receive(read, receive_buffer, 8192, 0); //receive response from client
mq_close(write);
mq_close(read);
mq_unlink("servertoclient");
mq_unlink("clienttoserver");
...
```

I am looking for a way to accomplish almost the same thing, but only using a single message queue at a time, not one for each direction simultaneously. The only difference is that with the single queue, simultaneous sending/receiving will not be supported, which is OK in my situation. Server and client will use some kind of special 'code' that signals a queue reversal. This is akin to a radio where you talk, then release the button and the receiver's radio beeps, letting them know you've finished talking. Then you listen to the receiver's message until your radio beeps. But the sender and receiver can never talk over each other.

Something along these lines:

Client:

```
open a single queue with mq_open for writing to the server
send some data
send a special message notifying the server that the queue is to be reversed
prepare queue for reading (not sure how to do this)
read data from server until the 'reverse' message is received, then revert queue to write
... keep going like this until a terminating message is received or client exits

unlink the queue
```

Server:

```
open a single queue with mq_open for reading from client
read in data
if the terminating message is read, 
   prepare queue for writing to client
send data and finish by sending the special 'reverse' message
prepare queue for reading
... keep going like this until a terminating message is received or server exits

unlink the queue
```

The client will always initiate the first message, so there is never any danger of the server wanting to send a message initially, for example.

I am not open to using any other method of interprocess communication (such as shared memory, sysv queues, pipes, tcp/udp, etc.).

Comment: Forgive me for asking, but why is this so important to you?

Comment: @PaulSanders I am trying to cut memory overhead in half, especially when there are many client processes connected to the server. With the two-queue method, the memory usage was quite high with so many queues (2 times the number queues as there are clients). If possible, I'd rather use only one queue per client-server connection to conserve resources.

Comment: OK, that sounds like a viable reason.  For future reference, it helps to put this kind of information in the original question.  And, I doubt there's a way, sadly.  You could maybe implement your own IPC queue,  based on shared  memory and whatever synchronisation primitives are appropriate.

Comment: I apologize if I wasn't clear in the original question. I would do my own implementation as a last resort, but I am confined strictly to a POSIX queue by a standards sheet. If I didn't have this constraint, I would definitely be using something like a SysV queue or socket. All I need to know is how to 'reverse' the flow of information in a POSIX queue. I have been tinkering with various placements of mq_close and mq_open but all of them have resulted in a segmentation fault or some kind of error code (most commonly EMFILE and EINTR). The OS I'm running this on is Ubuntu Linux, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that what you want to achieve will **not** work.

The basic concepts of POSIX message-queues are:

- multiple applications/threads may open the very same message_queue
- they all can write messages to the queue and/or read messages from the queue
- reading a message from the queue is **consuming**, i.e. the message consumed by one read isn't available anymore to any other client connected to the same message_queue

In your concrete setup with a message_queue, where exactly 2 participants are connected (one in the role as client, one in the role as server) you run into the following problem with your depicted logic:

After the Client has sent some messages (to be consumed by Server) and then sent special message/token, which shall signal, that from now on the Server shall write messages to the queue, the Client must make a decision, when to read again from the message_queue to check for replies from the Server.
Now there are potentially two cases:

1. Client had (luckily) waited long enough and the Server had already consumed all messages sent by the Client before. Then the Client will just read the new messages, the server had put into the queue for him.
2. Client was too fast and reads/consumes its own message BEFORE the Server had a chance to consume it. Then the whole protocol is broken.

Bottom line:
Since POSIX message queues:

- have destroying/consuming reads
- don't provide selectively reads by some identification of messages

what you want to achieve is not possible, unless you have an additional side-channel to synchronize client/server ... but this would be effectively the 2nd message_queue, which you want to get rid of.